# Beautifulsoup extract text and link from unordered list div < ul <li (Scandinavian characters)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, extract

Im attempting to extract the city names from the left hand side of this webpage (http://www.silvan.dk/butikker). The reason is that I need to extract the physical address of each city (which is found on the page that the link refers to, however, for the timebeing I started to extract the city names).
To be more exact from this container . However, as I only just started Python and Beautifulsoup I have not been able to extract the wanted information.

The result should give me:
City, city-link.

thus far I have:

```
import urllib2
import sys, locale, os, re
import lxml.etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def cp65001(name):
if name.lower() == 'cp65001':
    return codecs.lookup('utf-8')

html_page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.silvan.dk/butikker",'w')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
li = soup.select("ul > li > a")
for link in li:
    print link.get('href')
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
#1
#2
#3
#4    
#5
#6
#7
#8
#9    
#10
#11
#12
#13
#14    
#15
#16
#17
#18
```

I would appreciate very much if someone can direct me to a solution.
I tired using

```
div = soup.find('div', id='leftContent')
lis = div.find_all('li')
num_lis = len(lis)
```

But that stopped working after one run, and I dont know why?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your selector from:

```
li = soup.select("ul > li > a")
```

to:

```
li = soup.select(".subMenu li a")
```

output:

```
http://www.silvan.dk/butikker/ballerup
http://www.silvan.dk/butikker/birkeroed
http://www.silvan.dk/butikker/city2
http://www.silvan.dk/butikker/esbjerg
http://www.silvan.dk/butikker/fisketorvet
http://www.silvan.dk/butikker/fredericia
http://www.silvan.dk/butikker/frederikshavn
etc
```

you can find very good documentation of selectors [here](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and the direction to selectors. For some reason when I use your suggestion I do not get any output at all?

Comment: it worked for me, i run the code, but i removed the codec part. maybe we get different html? can you update the answer with the html you get?

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I tried removing the codec part aswell, but I do still not get any output at all, so I have _no_ html to show you. However, if I use

    li = soup.select("ul li a")

I get the same html output as previously. Im using python 2.7. Do I need to update some modules?

Comment: i mean this html:`html_page`. i personaly get a submenu class that has li inside that have a inside. do a `print html_page` and check where the elements are.

Comment: ahh, sorry I misunderstood. I get the following:
`<addinfourl at 444685484 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x02A6BOBO>>`

Another post suggested that i add `.read()` to my `html_page`. But then when I try to `print html_page` there is no output.

Any suggestions?

Comment: yes sorry `print html_page.read()` should give you the html of the page

Comment: I get an error:
`print html_page.read()`
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'.`

Comment: do we run the same code? because it works for me. if it says `'str' object has no attribute 'read'` then only `print html_page` should do the job.

Comment: i copied your code and changed the selector. i dont see how can we get so much different results